# Checkmate Puzzle

Tags: chess

I had a chess position today, in which my last position had 5 possible moves to checkmate. This seemed like a lot to me, and I immediately thought of the puzzle: *Which position would yield the maximum number of ways to checkmate the opponent on the next move*?

The rules of my made up puzzle are thus

1. Exactly 1 King per side
2. Any amount of any other kinds of pieces are allowed for either side
3. "Score" for the position is the number of winning moves there are

I came up with the following position. By my count, this has 70 total winning moves. I wonder what the maximum would be?

[image]

Follow up puzzles which occurred to me:

1. What's the fewest number of *pieces* for which every legal move would be checkmate?

   - Pawns aren't allowed
   - Exactly 1 King per side
   - White to move. All black pieces are counted in the answer
   - Alternate rule: you can only have one kind of piece, so there's a unique answer for each kind of piece
2. What's the fewest number of *points* for which every legal move would be checkmate?

   - Pawns aren't allowed
   - Exactly 1 King per side
   - White to move. All black pieces' points are counted in the answer
   - Q=9,R=5,B=3,N=3,K=3

Anyone have any suggested solutions to the above puzzles?

Comment: There are way too many questions in one here. The "main question" feels like it's probably a duplicate, but the follow-up questions seem nice.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's not an exact dupe, the earlier question requires a mate from a reachable position. It has an answer with [105 checkmates](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106309/36023).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highest number of mates](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30409/highest-number-of-mates)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the rules, you can easily construct cheap forced mates by

> putting white in check: (4 non-Kings, <s>16</s> 14 points)
>  [image]

And along the same lines, some single-piece boards:

> three queens or rooks, five bishops, or five knights should do the trick:
>  [image]

Comment: Good one. I hadn't considered putting the opposing side in check to force a capture as the only legal move. This is probably (close to?) the optimal solution for the additional puzzles. Perhaps I should've made a separate puzzle Q for each sub-puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

So many questions in one. Here's my answer to the follow-up question(s):

> 3 pieces, 13 points:

Which can be achieved like this:

> [image]
>
>  White's only legal move is **Kxb3#**.